# Monodevelop + IKVM : Java build error ("Error: invalid path: *.class")

Tags: java, monodevelop, ikvm

I am using the monodevelop Java plugin to compile a simple (hello world) Java project. The project is created fine, but when I try to build it I get the following error:

"Error: invalid path: *.class"

The command that triggers the error is as follows:

ikvmc -recurse:*.class -assembly:jTest -target:exe -debug -srcpath:/home/bob/src/jTest/jTest -r:mscorlib

Any idea what's going wrong, and how to fix this?

P.s. Please do not say "Mono is not for Java. Use (insert different Java IDE here) instead"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think **.\*.class** sould be run better. There must at minimum one slash in the path.